# Pygame doesnt open one specific mp3 file with error: "pygame.error: Unable to open file" but why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I want to import a file (https://github.com/clear-code-projects/UltimatePygameIntro/blob/main/audio/jump.mp3) its mp3 and pygame just wont do it no matter what I do. And yes guys I am aware that there is a lot of stuff on here with similiar questions, but literally none of their solutions has worked for me.

So as I ran the code on my MacBook it worked totally fine. Now I decided to copy the code onto my desktop PC which is windows. Everything works fine, as expected, except for that one file. The code looks like this:

```
self.jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("audio/audio_jump.mp3")
```

So because I did this part in a sprite class and also in another python file I won't call pygame.init(). Which wonders me the most about that it workes fine on my mac but not on my win pc? I use on both of them VS code and the newest python as pygame version. So probably you can help me out with my very specific problem.

I'll povide some example code here for my player sprite, but it might be a bit buggy.

player.py:

```
import pygame

class Test(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,screen):
        super().__init__()
        
        # universial pos & screen
        self.pos = pos
        self.screen = screen
        
        # setup player
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,100))
        self.image.fill("red")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        
        # setup variables
        self.gravity = 0
        self.jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("../pixel runner/audio/audio_jump.mp3") #"path/to/file"
        
    def apply_gravity(self):
        # keeps player at the same pos and applies gravity
        self.gravity += 1
        self.rect.y += self.gravity
        if self.rect.bottom >= self.pos[1]:
            self.rect.bottom = self.pos[1]
            
    def jump(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.gravity = -16
            self.jump_sound.play()   
                    
    def update(self):
        self.apply_gravity()
        self.jump()
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Overall I guess you can see what I will do and why this wont work for some reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound), `pygame.mixer.Sound` does only support .wav and .ogg files.

Answer (score 0):

So as it seems like `pygame.mixer.Sound()` doesn't support MP3 in PyGame 2.x, and because there is no mac support for PyGame 2.x yet it worked at my MacBook. So my solution was to use an [Audio Converter](https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav) because the file wont convert properly if you change the filename extension.